# Unable to connect to AWS instance on port 22

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, connection, timeout, telnet

We were able to ssh to the EC2 instance using the connect details until today; when it stopped working and I get the below error:

```
root@DKERP:~# ssh -i "gindustries.pem" ubuntu@ec2-15-184-231-34.me-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com

ssh: connect to host ec2-15-184-231-34.me-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com port 22: Connection timed out
```

Also, the telnet to public IP & port 22 is not working

```
root@DKERP:~# telnet 15.184.231.34  22
Trying 15.184.231.34...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out
```

The session manager is also failing to connect with the below error:

```
We weren't able to connect to your instance. Common reasons for this include:
SSM Agent isn't installed on the instance. You can install the agent on both Windows instances and Linux instances.
The required IAM instance profile isn't attached to the instance. You can attach a profile using AWS Systems Manager Quick Setup.
Session Manager setup is incomplete. For more information, see Session Manager Prerequisites.
```

There are no firewalls in AWS configurations.

Overview:
[image]
Security Groups:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
Instances:
[image]
[image]
Network Interface:
[image]
VPC:
[image]
Network ACLs:
[image]

The system logs are updated here: https://pastebin.com/RhAG5DzP

Kindly suggest.

Comment: Web ssh client (easy connect) also does not work?

Comment: does not work @Marcin

Comment: Maybe instance froze. Did you try rebooting it or launching new one?

Comment: have you tried to login via session manager and check `ufw`? I tried to telnet on your instance port 80 and it's 'available'(maybe you should close it for all) so the issue is not connectivity. Maybe the firewall blocks port 22

Comment: Restarts are not helping either

Comment: @Riz session manager is not working either. I have updated the Original post with the session manager error.

Comment: Can you check instance logs? `Select instance->Actions->Instance Settings->Get System Log`. Also, do you have a backup? or, you can stop the instance, attach the root ebs to another instance, go to sshd settings and maybe change the port to 2222 or anything you like and reattach and check. Ssm used to work or never tried  before?

Comment: @Riz there is no option on this forum to attach logs ... if you can suggest I will upload them.

Comment: @Ashar, I would suggest you to follow https://michael-ludvig.medium.com/recover-lost-access-to-your-ec2-instance-834f980dc304. The logs will help you(maybe) to understand what broke ssh. You can paste the logs on https://pastebin.com/ and share the link for other more competent members of this forum to read and understand.

Comment: @Riz I uploaded the logs here: https://pastebin.com/RhAG5DzP

Comment: How are you connecting to the instance? The Security Group says "Allow all traffic coming from `sg-0485...` -- this means it will only allow an inbound connection coming from a resource that is associated with that Security Group. If you are attempting to SSH from the Internet, it will block your inbound access. If you are connecting via a 'jump box', then make sure that the Jump Box is associated with that Security Group.

Comment: @Ashar, from the logs it seems like everything is working fine. I know you have already said that ssm is not working either but can you try send a command(even an echo `hello`) from system manager's `run command`. Does it work or it timesout as well?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein It does not allow me to delete as it says the default security group cannot be deleted.

Comment: Which security group is associated the instance? Is it `Default` or is it `launch-wizard-1`? You can see which one is being used by going to the **Network** tab on the EC2 instance in the console.

Comment: You're asking this at the wrong place. StackOverflow is for programming questions only. This sounds like it belongs to https://ServerFault.com

Comment: @JohnRotenstein it is `launch-wizard-1`

Comment: @JohnRotenstein you got this right !! deleting `launch-wizard-1` security group resolved the issue. Please post your answer for me to accept it. By the way great help and thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Connection timed out` message normally indicates that there is **no network connectivity**.

In most cases, this is due to the **Security Group**.

The steps to check it are:

- Select the instance in the Amazon EC2 management console
- Go to the **Security** tab
- Check the **Inbound rules**

To permit an SSH connection, there needs to be a rule that permits port 22 (SSH) and **the source set to your IP address** or from the whole Internet (`0.0.0.0/0`) -- preferably only your IP address so that everybody else will be blocked.

When launching an Amazon EC2 instance from the console, it will default to creating a new Security Group called `launch-wizard`. However, it is generally better to create your own Security Group with a useful name and only the rules you want. You can then re-use that Security Group in future for similar instances.

Comment: It doesn't make any sense at all! I am happy that it worked for @Asher but it's not a solution. He definitely had the ports open in the `launch-wizard-1` SG which was attached to the instance.